# Difficulty parsing a string with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I have a date string called `allianceStartDate` which has the value of

> "1/7/2010"

I am trying to convert this date string to util Date object. The code which I have tried is as follows:

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(allianceStartDate);
```

However the result of this operation is:

> Fri Jan 01 00:07:00 GMT 2010

The desired result is a Date object in the format: "01/07/2010".

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Instead of using `Date.parse(String)` use `Date.format(String)`. Also as said below, use `MM` for `Month`.

Comment: Date.format only allows you to pass a Date object as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `"dd/MM/yyyy"` not `"dd/mm/yyyy"`, We use `mm` for `minutes` not for `Month` in `Java`. You should use `MM` for month.

Read more about `Java` [SimleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: The date which is returned still is in the incorrect format... I would like it to be displayed as "01/07/2010" for example. I do not want the timestamp or the name of the month or day of the week.

Comment: @LiamWilson94 You need to format your printing format too. eg: `DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        Date d = df.parse("01/07/2010");
        System.out.println(df.format(d));`

Comment: I thought that after the SImpleDateFormat parse, the Date object should now be in the correct format?

Comment: @LiamWilson94 parsing will give you a date object. it can represent in any format you want.

Answer (score 1):

After parsing your initial text to obtain the Date object you will need to format it usig also a date formater in order to display it as a formatted text. Here is an exemple:

```
SimpleDateFormat SIMPLE_DATE_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

public String toSimpleDateFormat(Date d) {
    return SIMPLE_DATE_FORMATER.format(d);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains the difficulty I was having. I thought that after initially parsing the date that it would be in the desired format.